# Using Table 1 as Title column and Table 2 as Content columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

Table 1: Category Table

| CatCode | CatDesc | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAT0001 | Drinks | 22 |
| CAT0002 | Food | 12 |

Table 2: Product Table

| ProdCode | ProdDesc | Amount | CatCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P00001 | Coke | 10 | CAT0001 |
| P00002 | Pepsi | 12 | CAT0001 |
| P00003 | Burger | 5 | CAT0002 |
| P00004 | Fries | 5 | CAT0002 |
| P00005 | Eggs | 2 | CAT0002 |

I want to ask if it is possible to make a sql result where Table 1 contains the Category Code, Category Description, and Total but in the next column contains Table 2 which contains the Product Code, Product Name, and Quantity?

Expected outcome:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CAT0001 | Drinks | 22 |
| P00001 | Coke | 10 |
| P00002 | Pepsi | 12 |
| CAT0002 | Food | 12 |
| P00003 | Burger | 5 |
| P00004 | Fries | 5 |
| P00005 | Eggs | 2 |

Comment: I assume you only want to use SQL and not post process the result of a query with a progmaming language

Comment: Yes, I just need it to make a printable output.

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to write a Stored Proceedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try this (tested on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b95adea60a38840d70829ac5d9846b1b))

```
SELECT catcode as code, catdesc as name, total as amount
FROM (
  SELECT catcode, catdesc, total, catcode AS catcode2 FROM category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT prodcode, proddesc, amount, catcode AS catcode2 FROM product
) tmp
ORDER BY catcode2, catcode;
```

Comment: I tried to run the dbfiddle query on a navicat query but it returns like this:

          WITH tmp AS (
SELECT catcode, catdesc, total, catcode AS catcode2 FROM category
UNION ALL
SELECT prodcode, proddesc, amount, catcode AS catcode2 FROM product
)

SELECT catcode as code, catdesc as name, total as amount
FROM tmp
ORDER BY catcode2, catcode;
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tmp AS (
SELECT catcode, catdesc, total, catcode AS catcode2 FROM category
UNI' at line 1

Comment: I just found out that it didn't work because of the version of MySQL.

Comment: Can I have another way for this code in MySQL 5.7?

Comment: @entry_level_developer I have edited the code for version 5.7. Let me know if that works for you